# Is there any way to rename automatically page/post slugs with the page/post title in WP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to rename the slugs massively with the titles in Wordpress. Pages, Posts or Custom Posts in Wordpress. I've been investigating for a while but I can't find anything similar, not even with plugins.

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can code with php:

Include the wordpress functions in a external php file:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/var/www/path/to/your/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php');
require('/var/www/path/to/your/httpdocs/wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
```

Then:

- make DB backups
- `wp_query();` the desired posts(pages/categories/taxonomy/...)(https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)
- foreach query-result: `wp_update_term( int $term_id, string $taxonomy, array|string $args = array() )` 
  (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_term/)
- or `wp_update_post( array|object $postarr = array(), bool $wp_error = false )` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/)
- sudo be happy

Tom